# How to: Implement server forcing disconnect of client in GKSession

Tags: objective-c, ios, gksession

I am implementing the GKSession server/client mode operation in my application on iOS.  I found one [question related to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440953/how-to-disconnect-a-client-from-a-session-in-gksessionmodeserver-in-a-multiplayer) but with no answer.  I am trying to allow the server to disconnect any client that is currently connected to the session.  I thought that calling  disconnectPeerFromAllPeers:(NSString *)peerID would allow me to do this, but is seems to have no effect.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Just like to add that I have the same issue. disconnectPeerFromAllPeers: does not seem to work.

Comment: @monkeydom, sorry I didn't see this post earlier. I ended up implementing the disconnecting of peers by having the server send a request to the peer in the form of a data dictionary. I updated my post with explanations and example code of how I did this.

Comment: @JonnyB : you can answer your own question and accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Actually answered via question update ion 01/03/2012, but moved this text to the answer section*

I wanted to share how I implemented a disconnect request sent from server to client.  All of the code presented below is contained within a class I created to completely encapsulate all the interfacing with a GKSession instance (also implements the GKSessionDelegate methods).

First I have the server send a disconnect request to the client that shall be disconneted.  Any data that is sent from client to server or vice versa is contained within a dictionary that also has a key-value pair to specify the type of data that is sent (in this case the data is a disconnect request).

```
- (void)sendDisconnectRequestToPeer:(NSString *)peer {

//create the data dictionary that includes the disconnect value for the data type key
NSMutableDictionary *dictPrvw = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:GKSessionDataTypeDisconnect], kDictKeyDataType, nil];

NSData *dataChunk = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictPrvw] retain];
//[self printDict:dictPrvw];

NSArray *peers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:peer, nil];

[self sendData:dataChunk toPeers:peers];

[dataChunk release];
[dictPrvw release];

}
```

The client receives the data, casts it into a dictionary and examines the key-value pair that specifies what type of data was sent.  If it's a disconnect request, my "GKSessionManager" class then implements a disconnect.

```
- (void)recievedAllDataChunksInSession:(GKSession *)session fromPeer:(NSString *)peer context:(void *)context {

//The chunk was packaged by the other user using an NSKeyedArchiver, 
//so unpackage it here with our NSKeyedUnArchiver
NSMutableDictionary *responseDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *)[[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.recievedPackets] mutableCopyWithZone:NULL];

//[self printDict:responseDictionary];

//get the enumerator value for the data type
NSNumber *gkSessDataType = [responseDictionary objectForKey:kDictKeyDataType];
int intDataType = [gkSessDataType intValue];

UIAlertView *anAlrtVw;

switch (intDataType) {
    case GKSessionDataTypeMessageData:
        [self sessionManager:self recievedDataDictionary:responseDictionary];
        break;

    case GKSessionDataTypePreviewRequest:
        if (sess.sessionMode == GKSessionModeServer) {
            [self sendMsgPreviewToPeer:peer];
        }
        break;

    case GKSessionDataTypePreviewSend:
        //[self sessionManager:self recievedDataDictionary:responseDictionary];
        [self sessionManager:self connectedWithPrelimData:responseDictionary];
        break;

    case GKSessionDataTypeDisconnect:
        anAlrtVw = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                    initWithTitle:nil 
                    message:@"The server has disconnect you." 
                    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [anAlrtVw show];
        [anAlrtVw release];
        [self closeSession];
        [self disconnectedByServer];

    default:
        break;

}
}


- (void)closeSession {
  [sess disconnectFromAllPeers];
  [sess setDataReceiveHandler: nil withContext: NULL];
  sess.available = NO; 
  sess.delegate = nil;
  self.sess = nil;
  self.serverId = nil;
  self.rqstPeerId = nil;
  serverIsConnecting = NO;
}
```

The user never sees the disconnect request and so has no control over whether or not to deny it.

Hope this information helps.  I realize what I wrote my not be entirely clear and I have left a lot of other code out (on purpose) so feel free to comment or ask questions.